# Парсинг xml в Spring Batch

Tags: java, xml, spring

В Spring Batch есть процессор которым можно извлекать данные считанные в дефолтном reader.

Я считал файл xml он у меня лежит в бине

```
@Bean
    public FileItemReader<MyFile> reader(){
return new FileItemReader<MyFile>(){
//.}.build();
}
```

дальше не очень понимаю как из него достать нужный мне параметр, например name.