# Процессор в Spring Batch - Java EE

Tags: java, xml, spring, springbatch

у меня есть структура в Spring Batch.
1. xmlItemReader читает xml, в нем есть дата. Date one.
2. затем идет процессор, который должен по условию `if(one<current)` 
создавать список дат меньших сегодняшних.
3. затем запись этот список в файл txt.

пункт 1 реализован так

```
@Bean
    public ItemReader<Bic> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<Bic> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Bic>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.xml"));
        reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Bic>() {{
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                setNames(new String[]{"date"});
            }});
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Bic>() {{
                setTargetType(Bic.class);
            }});
        }});
        return reader;
    }
```

пункт 3 реализован так

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter itemWriter() {
        return  new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Foo>()
                                   .name("itemWriter")
                                   .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/test/output.txt"))
                                   .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
                                   .build();
}
```

как реализовать процессор с условием в п.2?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсинг xml в Spring Batch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859866/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-xml-%d0%b2-spring-batch)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, Foo это и есть список дат?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, почему нельзя использовать ItemProcessor?

```
public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<String, Foo {
  public Foo process(Bic item) {
    if (predicate){
        return new Foo();
      }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Остается только сформировать джобу.